# Running docker container for a test

Tags: node.js, docker, testing, mocha.js, integration-testing

I have an application with `nodejs` and `R code`. The last one runs in a Docker container.

I am planning some end-2-end tests, where I need to have the docker containers running. The service inside the container is stateful, so I would need to restart it for each test (for instance in `beforeEach`).

I would like to know what is the common way of doing this. I was thinking of  executing an external command from the code in `nodejs`. Somethink like `exec(docker run ...)`, but I don't know whether it is correct and elegant.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker deamon exposes RESTFul apis that you might want to take a look at. The [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.35/) api is documented and versioned.

It might be much cleaner to interact with this api rather than forking docker commands.